# Is Doflamingo blind in one eye?

Tags: one-piece

There's a theory about that Doflamingo wears his iconic glasses because he's blind to his (IIRC) left eye. It was assumed because whenever his eyes were shown (quite rarely), it was actully always only the left one.

Is there anything we can know about it in canon? Any kind of disease of injury that would possibly, even theoretically justify it?

Comment: Where did you read about this theory?

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade I can't really define an exact place, I read sources almost randomly, usually on Facebook and in the relevant sub of Reddit.

Comment: there's no mention of scar on Flamingo Eye on his wiki page. . . .

Comment: @NamikazeSheena I'm not necessarily implying a scar, but as I said, there's one eye that has never ever been shown,

Comment: I think the simplest answer to this question is No. There is nothing in canon that signifies Doflamingo missing an eye. This is just one of the many unproven theories, something a series as vast as One Piece would be cursed with. Unless Oda clarifies, the answer stays no.

Answer (score 3):

[image][image][image]

This theory is based on the glimpses of Doffy's childhood we get. While strung up one of the methods of torture mentioned involved blinding someone. The next panel shows an arrow being shot towards Doflamingo. We then suddenly get an image of two eyes as he wakes up, one without shades and one with shades with a reflection of fire in them.

But note that Doffy's eyes are covered with cloth while he's strung up. So that may not be his shades at all, but a symbolic representation. Considering his next action is to remove his shades, while clearly in distress, it's theorized that arrow hit it's mark and Doffy lost an eye that day.

Comment: Since the question I discussed this theory many times with many people who know this theory. Our conclusion is that is heavily implied and believable and would add a lot to Doffy's actual power, but as long as canon doesn't prove it, it stays as speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess i can assume that it is somehow of a correct theory, since in Doflamingo's past (as a little kid) you could see an arrow heading his way in the reflection of his sunglasses, as if they were heading for his left eye.
But if it even struck him is unknown.

Comment: If you could include the actual moment where this happened (chap num/page num | picture) this would actually be a good answer.